# Как установить gimp-python на Linux?

Tags: python, linux

Пытаюсь установить gimp-python на linux, чтобы использовать плагин heal selection

```
apt install gimp-python
```

Выдаёт:

```
 gimp-python : Depends: python:any
               Depends: python-gtk2
```

Чтобы установить эти пакеты, нужно установить python-minimal. При попытке его установить вылетает

```
python3-six (1.16.0-2) breaks python-minimal (<< 2.7.18) and is installed.
```

Что делать? Удалить python3-six?
Боюсь, что без него что-то перестанет работать.

Comment: Это на  ubuntu скачивашь?

Comment: @Master's Time, Kali

Comment: Вам нужен пакет для Python 3, а вы пытаетесь поставить куски Python 2.

Comment: @0andriy, gimp-python просит python2.7

Comment: Ну так обратитесь с поддержку дистрибутива, это их косяк по сборке, сейчас уже почти никто не хочет связываться с Python 2.

Comment: @0andriy, дистрибутив здесь ничего не сделает: гимп застрял на втором питоне... порт на третий есть в дев-версии, но там API полностью перекроили, так что старые скрипты работать не будут…

Comment: @Fat-Zer, по меньшей мере они могут не вводить пользователей в заблуждение, то есть вместо поставок плохо-поддерживаемых пакетов, лучше вообще ничего не поставлять. А так, в Gimp официальный язык скриптов Script-Fu.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/gimp`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install gimp gimp-gmic gimp-python`